# How to replace Ubuntu with Arch on a dual boot?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, grub2

I want to replace Ubuntu Linux on my current set up. Currently I have a dual boot with *Ubuntu Mate* and *Windows 10*. I would like replace the Ubuntu installation with Arch.

But before I do so I was wondering what preparation I should do before erasing `/dev/sdc` and reinstalling. I used Grub2 to chose which operating  system to start.

```
$ dpkg --list | grep grub 
ii  grub-common                                                 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                                 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files)
ii  grub-efi-amd64                                              2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                                 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-bin                                          2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                                 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 binaries)
ii  grub-efi-amd64-signed                                       1.66.17+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                         amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (EFI-AMD64 version, signed)
ii  grub2-common                                                2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.17                                 amd64        GRand Unified Bootloader (common files for version 2)
ii  grub2-themes-ubuntu-mate                                    0.3.7                                                   all          GRand Unified Bootloader, version 2 (ubuntu-mate theme)
```

So should the settings be saved? If yes how is this accomplished. Further down you see that I have three hard drives

```
$ parted --list
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB                                    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB  fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   240MB  134MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      240MB   250GB  249GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      250GB   250GB  472MB  ntfs                                       hidden, diag


Model: ATA ST1000LM024 HN-M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA KINGSTON SV300S3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   103GB  102GB   ext4
 3      103GB   120GB  17,1GB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do not need to do anything. Just remove the Ubuntu and install what you want. Grub2 new installation itself will find.

Answer (score 0):

First you should find your root partition of Ubuntu where Ubuntu is installed. While installing Arch just replace that partition(Select this for Arch Linux). It will be easy if you remove Ubuntu during Arch installation. For Grub2 it will ask you during installation just replace the previous one.